# Radio buttons from bootstrap V3.X adds name of radio into URL involuntarily

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use a radio button to determine where to redirect a user when they press enter.

Problem I have is when I select the radio button and press enter key the URL is populated with "searchpage?searchradios=animalname"

Below is a snippet with a basic example

[picture showing the involuntary addition to the URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbMXb.png)

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6" align="center">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="radio" name="searchradios" value="animalname">Animalname
            </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
    </div>
    <!-- /input-group -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

The plan is to have a button that triggers a script that will determine the selected radio button and determine which page to redirect to using window.location.href, but with the text field automatically adding information about the radio button to the URL the href does not work and only reloads the page with the unwanted information in the picture.

Comment: That has nothing to do with Bootstrap. This is how form controls work. If you don't want the radio values in the form submission, leave them out of the form.

Comment: Probably a stupid comment but are you using "POST" for form action?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your whole form it is hard to know, but it seems you are doing a GET and not a POST.